# Making an input tag dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am designing a chat application just like web whatsapp.

I have a class named as **chat-body** where the messages are displayed and I have another class named as **chattext** where the user can enter the message whatever he or she wants to send.

Now, what my question is how to make it dynamic?

(i.e if user enters some text in the chattext input tag and hits enter then the entered text should be displayed in the chat-body class.

[image: this is the screenshot of my chat application which I am designing]

```
<div class="chatbody">
  <div class="chatlogs">
    <div class="chatm self">
      <p class="chat-message">Hi rishabh<br><time style="color: gray;float: right">10.00</time></p>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="chatm friend">
      <p class="chat-message">Hi nishant<br><time style="color: gray;float: right">10.00</time></p>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="chatm self">
      <p class="chat-message">how r u<br><time style="color: gray;float: right">10.00</time></p>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="chatm friend">
      <p class="chat-message">thk hain, tm sunao..?<br><time style="color: gray;float: right">10.00</time></p>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="chatm self">
      <p class="chat-message">Hm v thk hain<br><time style="color: gray;float: right">10.00</time></p>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="chatm friend">
      <p class="chat-message">Aur kya ho rha h<br><time style="color: gray;float: right">10.00</time></p>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="chatm self">
      <p class="chat-message">Just chiling...tm kya kr rhe??<br><time style="color: gray;float: right">10.00</time></p>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="chatm friend">
      <p class="chat-message">Kch v nai..baithe hun<br><time style="color: gray;float: right">10.00</time></p>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="chatm self">
      <p class="chat-message">Aur btao kch naya<br><time style="color: gray;float: right">10.00</time></p>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="chatm friend">
      <p class="chat-message">Sb wai kch naya nai<br><time style="color: gray;float: right">10.00</time></p>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="chatm self">
      <p class="chat-message">haha..same here<br><time style="color: gray;float: right">10.00</time></p>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="chatm friend">
      <p class="chat-message">haha..same here<br><time style="color: gray;float: right">10.00</time></p>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="chatm self">
      <p class="chat-message">I cannot even imagine where I would be today were it not for that handful of friends who have given me a heart full of joy. Let's face it, friends make life a lot more fun<br><time style="color: gray;float: right">10.00</time></p>
    </div>
    <br>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="chattext">
  <i style="color:gray;font-size: 24px;padding-left: 5px;padding-right: 5px;" class="fa fa-smile-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Type a message">
  <i style="color:gray;font-size: 27px;padding-left: 20px;" class="fa fa-microphone" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: share your code

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck?  I see no JavaScript code here at all.

Comment: I have not wriiten the js code yet. I am not getting the logic to be applied.

Comment: Well then that's where you'd want to start.  Actually writing some JavaScript code.  An introductory tutorial on JavaScript seems like a reasonable place to start.  Let us know when you encounter a specific problem in your code.

Comment: what exactly i want is if someone enters text in input tag of class chattext and hits enter then the entered text should be displayed inside chatbody class as a part chatm self class.

Comment: @nishantsingh you must use ajax and keypress function for it

Comment: @Rtra can you show sample codes for that.

Comment: @nishantsingh check my answer

Comment: I guess it's better to use php to m make it dynamic, if you could learn it !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#input_field_id').bind("enterKey",function(e){
     //do stuff here
});
   $('#input_field_id').keyup(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13)
    {
        $(this).trigger("enterKey");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use Ajax function to post chat text but as you said you need to detect `Return Key` then here is the function for it

```
 $(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        alert('You pressed enter button!');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding form in your input

```
<form action="#" method="post">
   <input id="input_field_id" type="text" name="txt" onkeypress="handle(event)" />
</form>

function handle(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 13){
       e.preventDefault(); // Ensure it is only this code that rusn

       var message = $("#input_field_id").val();

       if(message == ""){
          alert("please enter message");
       }else{
          var html = '<div class="chatm self">' +
          '<p class="chat-message">'+message+'<br><time style="color: gray;float: right">10.00</time></p>' +
          '</div>';
          $(".chatlogs").append(html);
       }

       return false;

    }
}
```

Comment: what is not working. either it is not appending html or the function is never called

Comment: its not appending

Comment: have you assigned id to input field and tried alerting inside if condition

Comment: just give me some time

Comment: he has tried and i have also tried it the problem here is that while hitting enter it is executing the function but it is not entering into if conditon